# Ansible: Run as a different user on localhost

Tags: linux, ansible, localhost, ansible-inventory

I'd like to run a command on localhost, using `ansible_connection=local`, but also as a specific user, i.e. `ansible_user=my_other_user`. Interestingly, the two options seem to be mutually exclusive:

- With `/etc/ansible/hosts` being `localhost     ansible_user=my_other_user`

  - `ansible localhost -a "whoami"
    localhost | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
    my_other_user`
- With `/etc/ansible/hosts` being `localhost     ansible_user=my_other_user   ansible_connection=local`

  - `ansible localhost -a "whoami"
    localhost | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
    myself`

Is this a bug or a feature?

How can I use configure Ansible's Inventory to log on to localhost using my_other_user but without need to ssh?

EDIT: This should never use sudo through the local user `myself`. Passwords for users `myself` and `my_other_user` are different, and Ansible shall not know the password for `myself`.

EDIT2: Changing to method `su` (i.e. `localhost  ansible_connection=local    ansible_become_user=my_other_user   ansible_become_method=su    ansible_become=true`) does **not** work since it is then not possible to run commands as root without knowing the root password.

Comment: EDIT says you don't want Ansible to know current user's password. EDIT2 says you don't want Ansible to know the other user's password. So what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

There's `become` for that:

```
ubuntu@test:/$ ansible all -i 'localhost,' -c local -m shell -a 'whoami'
localhost | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
ubuntu

ubuntu@test:/$ ansible all -i 'localhost,' -c local -b --become-user=www-data -m shell -a 'whoami'
localhost | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
www-data
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me since it requires the password for user `ubuntu`, but I need Ansible to use the sudo password for `www-data`. Edited question for more precision.